# editpaste method not available

Tags: vba, copy-paste, ms-project

I am trying a simple code that cuts a tasks from one part of my project file and paste it on another part - code below.

when i am running the code it goes to debugging : runtime error 1100 : The method is not available in this situation. and it highlight Editpaste.
when i go to debug and run it (without any changes) it works fine!
please help how can i avoid runtime error pop

```vb
    Sub Move()

    Dim i As Integer

        i = ActiveCell.Task.id
     
        
        ' i want to manually select the task that i want to move:
        SelectRow Row:=0, rowrelative:=True
        EditCut
        
        ' I want to paste it on row 2 of my schedule
        
        SelectRow Row:=2, rowrelative:=False
        
         ' debugger stops here, but in debugging mode, running it again will work!
         EditPaste
        
        'this line goes back to were i was in the schedule
        Application.Find Field:="ID", test:="equals", value:=i + 1
     

    End Sub
```

Comment: This should work, so try a reboot, use a single-pane view such as Gantt Chart, and try inserting a `DoEvents` before the EditPaste line.

Comment: thanks @Rachel for your response. I added  `sleep(4000)`    before the paste and didn't face any issues after doing so. I am going to try your solution too.